# Upgrading my current build for gaming purposes

Tags: gaming, pc, desktop

I am investigating the possiblities of upgrading my current build for games like: Fallout 4, SC2: LotV and Star Wars: Battlefront.

**My current build:**

**CPU:** AMD A10-7600

**CPU cooler:**  Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO

**Motherboard:** MSI A88XM-E35

**RAM:** Kingston HyperX Savage 2x4GB DDR3 2133Mhz

**GPU:** Nvidia GeForce GT630 2GB DDR3

**Storage:**

- Kingston SSDNow 120GB SSD
- An array of 3 hard drives consisting of a 250 GB and two 1TB drives

**PSU:** A 550 watt power supply (I'll look up which brand it is)

I want to know what to upgrade, since I had the following things  already pointed out:

- Sticking to DDR3 RAM (and it's pretty cheap to get another kit of 8GB)
- I prefer to upgrade my card to the AMD R9 380 card instead of a Nvidia GTX950 or whatever
- I will stick to gaming at 1920 x 1080
- Keeping the upgrades as ‘cheap’ as possible (want to make the most of my current parts)
- My budget ranges from 300 to 500 euros in total (considering I want to upgrade certain components and not buying a completely new build).

Comment: At the moment, this post is rather too broad for us to answer effectively. We'll need to know some more details - budget, for one, among others. Also, this should be split out into multiple questions, one for each component you want us to recommend you hardware for. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like before this question can be reopened we need to know why you were using a GT630 - it's lower-performing than the GPU in your CPU. Was there a need for Nvidia technology at some point?

Comment: My guess that it was the best I could get for the budget that I had at the time. The card has been replaced by a AMD Radeon R9 380 last year.

Answer (score 4):

### Upgrading your GPU

Guessing at your budget, I'm going to recommend a *[R9 380](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r9#)*, or *[GTX 960](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-960/specifications)*. Both are pretty equal cards, and the GTX 960 pulls ahead in nVidia optimized games but I'm not going to go into that. Upgrading to either will be an extreme improvement to your current GPU. [(Benchmarks)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0HzWW6mDno)

### Upgrading CPU

If you are looking to upgrade your CPU, **which in my opinion you don't really need to do**, I would recommend something along the lines of the [i5-6600K](http://ark.intel.com/products/88191/Intel-Core-i5-6600K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz), because of the 14nm architecture, higher IPC, and newer chipset. Unfortunately, upgrading your CPU would require you to upgrade your motherboard to Z170. I'm not going to write a motherboard recommendation as well.

### <strike>Upgrade RAM</strike> (Don't)